# WPF ListView ignores SelectedItem-change

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I am working with a ListView in WPF which is bound an observable collection. I then bound the SelectedItem-Property to a property of the ViewModel.

- When I select an item in the ListView via GUI "SelectedItem" is changed.
- When I change "SelectedItem" in the ViewModel, the ListView only changes, when I set the SelectedItem to NULL.
- When I set any other (valid!) object (like the first entry of the ObservableCollection) the ListView just ignores it.

Furthermore: When I want to "Veto" a SelectedItem Change (because data is not saved), the ListView  highlights the new selected item instead of the SelectedItem-Property of the ViewModel.

I already tried to change the Binding to `Mode=TwoWay` - doesn't work as well (otherwise the "NULL" change to SelectedItem wouldn't work as well)

This is the code from the view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserConfiguration}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="User Configuration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ConfigurationName}" Width="200" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserConfigurationViewModel> Configurations { get; private set; }
private UserConfigurationViewModel _selectedUserConfiguration;
public UserConfigurationViewModel SelectedUserConfiguration
{
  get { 
    return this._selectedUserConfiguration; 
  }
  set
  {
      if (this._selectedUserConfiguration != null && this._selectedUserConfiguration.WasChanged)
      {
        if (ask-user)
        {
          this._selectedUserConfiguration.Reset();
          this._selectedUserConfiguration = value;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        this._selectedUserConfiguration = value;
      }
      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedUserConfiguration);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, could the problem be that the `SelectedItem` property of the ListView is of type `object` and your `SelectedUserConfiguration` property is of type `UserConfigurationViewModel`?

Comment: How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In order to select the selected item in any collection control from code, the selected item *must* be an actual item from the collection that is bound to the `ItemsSource` property. This can be achieved easily enough with `LinQ` if your collection items have at least one unique property:

```
SelectedUserConfiguration = Configurations.Where(c => c.UniqueProperty == 
    valueOfItemToSelect).FirstOrDefault();
```

If your data type objects do not have a unique property, you can simply add an `int Id` property for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same issue with a TabControl.

I've tried to create a int property and bind it to SelectedIndex, but no success.

Strangely enough this did the trick:

In your ListView set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`

Set a `ListView.Resources` like this:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```